# What is the difference between direct initialization of class member vs doing it within a method?

Tags: java, static, class-members

I have done a Google Foobar task and was curious about why 2 implementations, which seems to be equivalent, work in a different way. The first one brings me "Test 2 failed", when the second solution passes all test cases. I know that both of them don't follow the best OOP practices, but I am interesting what is the exact problem with the 1st implementation.

1.

```
public class Answer {
    static Map<Character, LinkedList<Character>> g = new HashMap<Character, LinkedList<Character>>();
    static Set<Character> visited = new HashSet<Character>();
    static ArrayList<Character> ans = new ArrayList<Character>();

    public static void dfs(char v) {
        visited.add(v);
        //some standard code for DFS
        ans.add(v);
    }

    public static String topologicalSort() {

        for (Character element : g.keySet()) {
            if (!visited.contains(element))
                dfs(element);
        }

        //some code to prepare the output
    }

    public static void builGraph(String[] words) {

        //some code to build adjacency list and then use it through g reference 
    }

    public static String answer(String[] words) {

        if (words.length == 1) {
            //some code
        }

        builGraph(words);

        return topologicalSort();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //some code
        System.out.println(answer(words));
    } 
}
```

2.

```
public class Answer {
    static Map<Character, LinkedList<Character>> g;
    static Set<Character> visited;
    static ArrayList<Character> ans;

    public static void dfs(char v) {
        visited.add(v);
        //some standard code for DFS
        ans.add(v);
    }

    public static String topologicalSort() {
        visited = new HashSet<Character>();
        ans = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (Character element : g.keySet()) {
            if (!visited.contains(element))
                dfs(element);
        }

        //some code to prepare the output
    }

    public static void builGraph(String[] words) {

        g = new HashMap<Character, LinkedList<Character>>();

        //some code to build adjacency list and then use it through g reference 
    }

    public static String answer(String[] words) {

        if (words.length == 1) {
            //some code
        }

        builGraph(words);

        return topologicalSort();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //some code
        System.out.println(answer(words));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you clear your containers (Map, Set, ArrayList) in the 1st implementation?
A test case might call answer() multiple times, so
I would change answer() method from the 1st implementation to something like:

```
public static String answer(String[] words) {
    this.g.clear();
    this.visited.clear();
    this.ans.clear();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You are right about that I need to clear my containers in answer() function. However, a test case by itself calls answer() function only once. Possibly, there are many test cases one after another and all of them are in the same main() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the test is checking, so I don't know why it's failing. However, it's easy to tell the differences between the two implementations.

In Java (quoting the [4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)):

> For all reference types ([§4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is `null`.

The objects in second case are assigned `null` until you initialize them, and you do that on *each* call of `topologicalSort`. So every time the method is called, a *new* object will be created.

In the first implementation, you only initialize them once - when the class is created. This should be enough for you to dig more into the problem and better understand why the test is failing in the first implementation.

Comment: I understand what you wrote, but the thing is topologicalSort function being called only once per test case. Also, I still don't understand why the result may differ in this particular case.

Comment: @ruvinbsu It depends on the test, maybe other tests assume the result of the previous tests, for some reason..

Comment: Interesting assumption and possibly you are right. Although, it seems to be a bit strange that Google didn't warn us about it. Anyway thanks a lot.